# How to notify the android user if camera permission is denied

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am working with camera permissions. when the user clicks on `take photo` button, user will be shown with run time permissions menu and lets say user deny's it and then clicks on `take photo` button, run time permissions will be shown second time.

after this clicking the `take photo` button nothing happens.

What I want to do is, after the second attempt, i want to show a popup telling the user to go to settings to change the permissions.

How can I know if the user has denied the permission twice.

this is what I have coded so far

[image]

```
takePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener {
        takePhoto()
    }

private fun takePhoto() {
    activity?.let {
        if (isCameraPermissionsAllowed()) {
            capturePhoto()
        } else {
            permReqLauncher.launch(
                CAMERA_PERMISSION
            )
        }
    }
}

private val permReqLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        val granted = permissions.entries.all {
            it.value == true
        }
        if (granted) {
            capturePhoto()
        }
    }


private fun capturePhoto() {
    onUtilityBillTypeListener.onUtilityBillTypePhotoLink(true)
}
```

where is the right place to add this dinielDialog

```
private fun showPermissionDeniedDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this.requireContext())
        .setTitle("Permission Denied")
        .setMessage("Permission is denied, Please allow permissions from App Settings.")
        .setPositiveButton("Settings",
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, i ->
                // send to app settings if permission is denied permanently
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(this.requireContext()), null)
                intent.data = uri
                startActivity(intent)
            })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .show()
}
```

Comment: Why not just save if the user already denied permission in a boolean or better in a shared preference? So you can recall the state from the settings menu as well.

Comment: Hello @thefeiter that can be done, but is there a camera permissions method that tells me if permission has been denied

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this

```
if (isCameraPermissionsAllowed()) {
            capturePhoto()
        } else {
            if (permissionDeniedFlag) {
                showPermissionDeniedDialog()
            } else {
            permissionDeniedFlag = True
            permReqLauncher.launch(
                CAMERA_PERMISSION
            )
        }
```

With an initial declaration of `var permissionDeniedFlag = False`.

Answer (score 0):

On your code where you're getting permission result you can do it like this :

```
private val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
            isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) //perform action
        else {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            builder.setTitle("Permission Required!")
            builder.setMessage("We need permission in order to perform this action.")
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                showPermRationale()
                dialog.cancel()
            }
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }
            builder.show()
        }
    }

private fun showPermRationale() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
    val uri = Uri.fromParts(
        "package", requireActivity().packageName, null)
    intent.data = uri
    requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: I can trigger on else statement but that will trigger the first two times as well when user denys the camera permission. I only want to trigger the settings dialog only after two attempts

Comment: Then you can use the permission rationale by applying else if condition which makes sure that first two attempts are already performed.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it by adding this code

```
 private fun takePhoto() {
        activity?.let {
            if (isCameraPermissionsAllowed()) {
                capturePhoto()
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        this.requireActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    )
                ) {
                    showPermissionDeniedDialog()
                }
                else{
                    permReqLauncher.launch(
                        CAMERA_PERMISSION
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```